# Increase of entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, universe

We know that entropy increases due to heat. But the universe's heat is constant as heat cannot be created.So why does universe's entropy increase?

Comment: What you mean by universe's heat is constant?

Comment: Currently, the background temperature of the observable universe is around 2.7K. In the past, we know it was at least 3400K. The "universe's heat", if you want to use that phrasing, is decreasing. Furthermore, heat is just one of many forms of energy, which means you absolutely can create or destroy heat

Answer (score 0):

Entropy does not solely depend on heat.

By definition, entropy is the number of possible configurations of a system, given certain macroscopic properties (such as heat or volume).

Consider two objects at different temperatures, and suppose they are isolated from the environment, so they don't lose or gain heat from it. Now if we bring them into contact, we know heat flows from one to the other. The total amount of heat in this two-object system remains the same, but entropy has increased.

In fact, the reason heat flows from the hotter object to the cooler one is that there are more possible configurations for the system when heat is distributed evenly throughout, than when it is all crammed into one place.

This increase in the number of configurations for the system is exactly what it means to increase the entropy. As you can see, it is possible without adding heat to the system.